# Change Bootstrap Entries in Eclipse Run Configuration

Tags: eclipse, java-8, migration, run-configuration

I'm currently migrating from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8 and I'm facing a little problem with my Run Configuration in Eclipse: On the *Classpath* tab, there are two sections (namely *Bootstrap Entries* and *User Entries*). In the *Bootstrap Entries* section, it says **JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]**.

However, I set Java 1.8 as my default runtime environment in Eclipse's preferences already. I do have several Run Configurations and some already point to a 1.8 JRE, I previously installed. But it is not possible to edit the entry in the Run Configuration dialog.

So, I wonder:

- What actually is a *Bootstrap Entry*?
- Where does it come from?
- Where can I modify it from 1.7 to 1.8?

Comment: It should point to the correct library, unless you changed it (which contradicts your statement that this was not possible). At least, you should be able to click on “Restore Default Entries” after selecting “Bootstrap Entries”.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with JBoss 6.3.0 EAP. I was trying to upgrade from Java 1.6 to 1.7, but the Bootstrap entries were coming back to the previous value as soon as I closed the pop-up. 
Go to Window-> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and remove the earlier version of Java from there.
Come back to the window and your only existing JDK version will reflect. Have not tried this with Tomcat, but it might solve the problem.
Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For launch configurations the JRE is *not* configured via the `Classpath` tab, but on the `JRE` tab - if you are launching a `Java Application` (some other kinds of launch configurations have it on their `Main` tab).

What you see as "Bootstrap Entries" directly reflects your choice on the above tab of the dialog.

Comment: This is not true, at least for my setup. The *Bootstrap Entries* are not affected, when I change the JRE version on the **JRE** tab.

Comment: Well, bootstrap entries _should_ reflect the selected JRE and that's the way it works for me. If you have reproducible steps showing that this doesn't work, please consider filing a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=Debug

Comment: Just to double check: there's many places where you can select a JRE. You did try changing it in the very same launch configuration dialog? BTW, you may want to save the launch configuration to file (Tab Common > Save as > Shared file: ) and let us have a look at the file.